# How to define printfn equivalent in F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Since I do research with F# (in particular, using F# interactive), I'd like to have switchable "print-when-in-debug" function.

I can do

```
let dprintfn = printfn
```

F# interactive says

```
val dprintfn : (Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a)
```

and I can use

```
dprintfn "myval1 = %d, other val = %A" a b
```

whenever I want in my scripts.

Now I'd like to define `dprintfn` differently, so that it would *ignore* all its arguments yet being syntax-compatible with `printfn`. How?

---

The closest (yet non-working) variant I have in mind is:

```
let dprintfn (arg: (Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a)) = ()
```

but it the following doesn't compile then `dprintfn "%A" "Hello"`, resulting in `error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied`.

**P.S.** I currently use an alias for `Debug.WriteLine(...)` as work-around, but the question is still interesting for understading F#'s type system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `kprintf` function, which formats a string using the standard syntax, but then calls a (lambda) function you specify to print the formatted string.

For example, the following prints the string if `debug` is set and otherwise does nothing:

```
let myprintf fmt = Printf.kprintf (fun str -> 
  // Output the formatted string if 'debug', otherwise do nothing
  if debug then printfn "%s" str) fmt
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. But if you know the type of `printfn` and how to define your own func with the same signature, that would be very interesting and helpful. (Or... does F# treats `printfn` in a specific way, not just like any other function?)

Comment: String literals are implicitly convertible to this type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370359.aspx which is where the magic is.

Comment: The F# compiler has special support for `printf` formatted strings, and the static analysis of types associated with them. `kprintf` is the standard way to take advantage of that in your own functions.

Answer (score 3):

I've been profiling my application and found that debug formatting causes significant **performance issues**. Debug formatting occurs on almost every string of the code, due to the nature of the application.
Obviously, this has been caused by `kprintf` which unconditionally formats and then passes a `string` to a predicate.
Finally, I came up with the following solution that may be useful for you:

```
let myprintf (format: Printf.StringFormat<_>) arg =
    #if DEBUG 
        sprintf format arg
    #else
        String.Empty
    #endif

let myprintfn (format: Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>) arg =
    #if DEBUG
        printfn format arg
    #else
        ()
    #endif
```

Usage is quite simple, and format checking works fine:

```
let foo1 = myprintf "foo %d bar" 5
let foo2 = myprintf "foo %f bar" 5.0

// can't accept int
let doesNotCompile1 = myprintf "foo %f bar" 5
// can't accept two arguments
let doesNotCompile2 = myprintf "foo %f bar" 5.0 10

// compiles; result type is int -> string
let bar = myprintf "foo %f %d bar" 5.0
```